# How can I change the state of widget based on the action of another widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am having trouble with the following problem:

In this page, I have a CheckBoxListTile and two radioButtons.
I need to implement some rules, like these one:

- If any checkbox gets checked, disabled and unselect all radiobuttons
- If any radiobuttons gets selected, uncheck and disable all checkboxes

However, I can't get this to work. I've tried using statefulWidgets for both checkbox and radiobutton, but the logic was getting very messy.

I've tried to use a stateful widget for the PostView class, but since I'm using a futureBuilder there, whenever I called setState(), the whole page would be rebuilt and the checkbox would not get checked.

I believe there is a cleaner solution to this, but right now I can't see it.

Here is the snippet of the code so you can see ( this is using a stateless widget, I know I cannot do it this way, but It is just to show you guys what I am trying to do ):

```
Widget _buildFooter(Post postInfo) {
  return Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildRadioButtons(postInfo),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('press'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class PostView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  PostView(this.id);

  Post postInfo;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: ApiService.getpostInfo(id),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
          if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapShot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('error'),
              );
            }
            postInfo = postInfo.fromJson(snapShot.data);
            return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Divider();
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return _buildHeader(postInfo);
                }
                if (index == (postInfo.authors.length + 1)) {
                  return _buildFooter(postInfo);
                }
                index = index - 1;
                return _buildCheckboxListTile(postInfo, index);
              },
              itemCount: (postInfo.authors.length) + 2,
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

_buildCheckboxListTile(Post postInfo, index) {
  return CheckboxListTile(
    title: Text(postInfo.authors[index].name),
    value: postInfo.authors[index].checked,
    onChanged: (bool value) {
        ***Here I need to disabled the radiobuttons in case I get a true

    },
  );
}

_buildRadioButtons(Post postInfo) {
  return Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: postInfo.value1,
          title: Text('value1'),
          onChanged: (bool value) {
              *** here I need to uncheck all the checkboxes mentioned above
               in case the radio button is selected
          },
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          value: postInfo.value2,
          title: Text('value2'),
          onChanged: (bool value) {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Would this behaviour be possible without a statefulWidget?

Since I'm learning Flutter, any other advices regarding the code are welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try State Management libraries to easily manage state without the code getting messy. Here is a great article on the best state management libraries to use:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-app-architecture-101-vanilla-scoped-model-bloc-7eff7b2baf7e

In the case of Scoped Model, which for me is the simplest,and which I personally use, you can set both to be a child of a ScopedModel widget and have them notify each other once the state changes.

Comment: I see. I had already used Scoped Model when I was first learning flutter, but it also was difficult to manage it as the application grew. However, I liked the article you sent and I'm going to read it and try to chose a nice way to do it. Blocs seems a good alternative.  Thanks